# trainee programmer: man pages of input_sync(),input_report_key,input_event()

Tags: linux, device-driver

i want to get explanation of functions line input_sync(),input_report_key,input_event().. when i search for it i only get the definition of these function .. am a newbie in this driver programming and i really need simple explanations like man pages .. so that i can know what these functions actually do??

regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tutorial covering the methods in which you are interested in the Documentation/input folder in input-programming.txt. You can browse the latest version of it online at [git.kernel.org](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=tree;f=Documentation/input;h=47857954ed32cd9bec9aaffc93bb06add12258e9;hb=HEAD)